# traversing neo4j with multiple unique conditions

Tags: neo4j

Is possible traversing neo4j database giving more than a single unique conditions? for example making the database to answer the following literal question:

how many illness are directly related to everyone of these synthoms: head ache; sight loss; low blood pressure?

Traversal API talks about one unique condition (all descendant of pet0 that are owned by principal2; so my question. It's for a project.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Code snippets, some idea of how your database is organized, what you've tried so far. It will make your question much easier to address.

Comment: question helds sufficient elements to get answered, so far the answer of Tim Kuehn is what I was looking for. Please stop underscore people basing on personal tastes.

Answer (score 0):

If  you have a set of nodes labeled as symptoms, and a set of nodes labeled as illnesses that are linked to their symptoms, then this is how you'd find all the illnesses with the identified symptoms:

```
MATCH(:Symptom {condition: "head ache")-[:ILLNESS]->(i:Illness)
MATCH(:Symptom {condition: "sight loss")-[:ILLNESS]->(i)
MATCH(:Symptom {condition: "low blood pressure")-[:ILLNESS]->(i)
RETURN i
```

When you're looking to "and" a set of values like this, you're looking for a  node that has a relationship with a set of nodes with the identified property values.